# Reload header in section without reloading section rows in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction, uitableviewsectionheader

I'm trying to reload `UITableView` section Header instead of reloading the whole section's rows because I have a `UITextfield` in the row and when I call `tableview reloadSection`s it's clear the textfield value.

Comment: Think the other way round: Save the value of the text field in the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 0)
self.tableView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none)
```

You can reload the tableview with this code. You dont need to reload header for showing items

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```